# Scrambled looking records in F#-Interactive

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#, f#-interactive

When trying to print

```
pop
```

I get all this weird looking formatting in F# interactive, which basically turns the printing useless. Is there someway other to correctly format this?

[image]

The code is the following:

```
#light

open System
let rng = new Random()

type Individual = { x:int; y:int }
type ScoredIndividual = { individual:Individual; score:int }

let genGene() = rng.Next(-10, 10)
let genRandInd() = { x=genGene(); y=genGene() }
let genRandPop popSize = [ for _ in 1 .. popSize -> genRandInd() ]
let getScoredPop f pop = List.map (fun i -> { individual=i; score=(f i)}) pop

let fitnessFun ind = ind.x * ind.x + ind.y * ind.y

let pop = 30 |> genRandPop |> getScoredPop fitnessFun
```

Comment: Can you add the code in the image to a selectable code block so that we can easily copy & paste and play around with it?

Comment: You mean something more complex than: `pop |> List.iter (printfn "%A")`

Comment: Have you tried overriding `ToString`?

Comment: @Daniel: I'd like to avoid it, if possible :(

Comment: @pblasucci: that's better. yet the problem seems to be having records inside records. it seems like it'll try to always put a new line after the end of a record.

Comment: Don Syme's article I linked to in my answer shows how to use `AddPrintTransformer` to customize output for specific types.

Comment: thanks - FYI, the `#light` declaration is default as of F# 2.0 and no longer needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `ToString` or use [`StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370334.aspx) to customize the string representation. This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx) contains some useful information about customizing output in fsi.

Comment: One more question. Is it in some way possible to send things to fsi without printing anything in it? For instance, I'd like to send "pop" to fsi, so I can make some operations over it, without having it printing all the 947 individuals pop has.

Comment: You might keep a little function around for toggling `ShowDeclarationValues`. You can set it to false prior to sending `pop` to fsi. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321031/how-does-fsi-showdeclarationvalues-work

Comment: You can also turn off printing just for sequences: `fsi.ShowIEnumerable <- false`

Answer (score 3):

you might want to do fsi.AddPrinter for your ScoredIndividual type to control what's written to the console

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty rough, and I couldn't find any "easy" way to fix it. However, [FsEye](http://code.google.com/p/fseye/) can make it nicer (while it does delete the newlines, those spaces are in there good):

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Seems an interesting thing to have around. I see you are the author of it. It does seem to lag a lot, though.

Comment: @Stephen: Would it make sense for FsEye to normalize whitespace (outside of string literals) prior to display?

Comment: @devoured elysium - the lag is probably due to this issue: http://code.google.com/p/fseye/issues/detail?id=14&can=1, which only happens with objects that have large print trees like `pop` here. However, I attempted to fix it and it works "instantly" on both my slow work computer and fast home computer -- if you like, I'd be happy for you to add to the issue with details about your experience including your computer specs

Comment: @Daniel - that's an idea I like but I think it would be impossible to detect the start and end of string literals since 1) they may be nested, 2) there is no difference between opening and closing quotes. However, I could see about given special treatment to records and writing a custom printer.

Comment: In the OPs example the pattern is `\n\s{2,}`. It might be enough to replace just those with a single space.

Comment: @Daniel - Hmm, I'm not sure how I would use that, currently watch values are printed using the `sprintValue` function starting on line 65 in http://code.google.com/p/fseye/source/browse/tags/1.0.0-final/FsEye/WatchModel.fs which primarily relies on `sprint "%A"`

Comment: @Stephen - Looks like `cleanString` is already doing something similar. It might be as simple as changing `[\t\r\n]` to `[\t\r\n](?:\s+(?=\s))?`.

Comment: @Daniel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2499/discussion-between-stephen-swensen-and-daniel)